# Simple PHP Image Scroller

Tags: php

I'm very new to PHP and I'm trying to build a simple image scroll-through which would consist of the picture as well as a next link and a previous link which would go to the next/previous pictures stored in a directory. Right now all I have is an array of the filenames.

I did a bit of searching and haven't found any tutorials on doing this, but does anyone know of any links where I might find some help? Thanks.

Comment: You could use PHP to load the images from your source and do the image-scroll through JavaScript :) There are more than enough jQuery image viewers available. Calling the server on each press of previous or next might make your application look slow

Answer (score 2):

well you could link the array index through get
and then use it as key to show the url of the image

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v){

echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?index='.$k.'"></a>';//creates the link for diffrent images
}

echo '<img src="'.$array[$_GET['index']].'"/>';//show the image
```